# Cleanse a shell runtime environment to run system Perl?

Tags: bash, shell, perl

I need to create a several Perl programs on a Solaris 9 SPARC environment running Oracle EBS, one of which will be run from cron. The UNIX account that will be running Perl has all the environment variables set up to run Oracle-centric programs, so when I run "/usr/bin/perl -V", I get the following compilation error. Fortunately, the cron run Perl is not impacted by the Oracle environment settings.

```
bash-2.05$ /usr/bin/perl -V
Perl lib version (5.00503) doesn't match executable version (5.008) at /u01/app/applmgr/pr/iAS/Apache/perl/lib/5.00503/sun4-solaris/Config.pm line 7.
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

My first thought was to use the BEGIN block to do some house cleaning so I can use the system Perl rather than the Oracle EBS supplied version.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

BEGIN {
  delete $ENV{PERL5LIB};
  delete @INC[0..$#INC];
  push @INC, map { "/usr/local/lib/perl5/$_" } (
    '5.8.0','5.8.0/sun4-solaris',
    'site_perl','site_perl/5.8.0','site_perl/5.8.0/sun4-solaris'
  );
}

print "Hello clean Perl environment! :)\n";
```

I am not permitted to modify the UNIX account's local profile, so is this the proper way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Is there a `perl` binary under `/u01/app/applmgr/pr/iAS/Apache/perl` as well? It may be simpler to use that rather than the system `perl` binary.

Comment: Does Solaris 9 have `env -i`?

Comment: @chepner - Yes. There is a perl binary, but I have to tread lightly with this environment since its tied to the ERP system.

Comment: @jordanm - That is the solution. When you answer with that I will accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `-i` option of the `env` command allows you to start programs in a clean environment. From then `env` manpage:

```
   -i, --ignore-environment
          start with an empty environment
```

For you perl example:

```
env -i perl -V
```